# .onchange or .onclick and checkbox value to JS script

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have an array of checkboxes group into class='year'. I would like to call a function in JS when a checkbox is checked.

The html is,

```
<table class="inner" id="searchTable">
                                         <search>Exam Type:<th>                        
                                                    <?php 
                                                        foreach($exams as $key=>$value):

                                                               echo "<tr><td class='left'><input type='checkbox' class='year' id='$key' name='$key' value='$value'

                                                            if ($category['selected'])
                                                            {
                                                            echo ' checked';
                                                            }

                                                            > $value</td></tr>";
                                                          endforeach; ?>
                                     </table>
```

This table is inside a form. but I am too  worried about the form at the moment.

The JS should create a table with a row when any checkbox is checked.

```
function yearTable(){
    var table = document.getElementById("searchYear");
    var row = document.createElement("tr");    
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    var empty = document.createTextNode("year.value");
    /*var empty = document.createTextNode("");*/
    cell.appendChild(empty);
    row.appendChild(cell);
    table.appendChild(row); 
}

document.getElementByClassName('year').onchange = yearTable;
```

I have tried using .onchange and .clicked but neither do anything when a box is checked.
Also I need the value checked in the JS.
I tried year.value but that doesn't work. Prviously I has a select options menu with id = 'exam' and I was able to get the value using exam.value but I can't figure out how to do soemthing equivalent for these checkboxes.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While an html document may contain only one element with a specific id, there can be several elements with the same class.

So, there is no such a function as `document.getElementByClassName`. There is a function `document.getElementsByClassName`, and it returns an array of elements, so could call that function and then iterate over its return value, setting the needed callbacks.

Also, the code you posted must have thrown an exception at this line:

`document.getElementByClassName('year')`

So if you looked at [developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) in Chrome or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox, you would probably see an error.

Comment: Yes you are correct, plural needed. And i see how to get the value now.

Answer (score 0):

Got it,

```
function yearTable(){
    var year = this.value; 

    var table = document.getElementById("searchYear");
    var row = document.createElement("tr"); 
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    if (this.checked){
       var empty = document.createTextNode(year);
    }
    cell.appendChild(empty);
    row.appendChild(cell);
    table.appendChild(row); 
}

var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('year');
    for(var index in checkboxes){
        checkboxes[index].onchange = yearTable;
    }
```

Thanks